# Receive multipart messages in C with ZeroMQ

Tags: c, sockets, zeromq

I am writing a data recording system for a device that will transmit data using the ZeroMQ socket and publish multipart messages.

My program will need to be written in C.

I did manage to write a Python scripts which works exactly as it should.
This looks like this:

```
import zmq
import time
import numpy as np

_HEARTBEAT_PREFIX =     b'ray.heartbeat\0'  
_RAW_DATA_PREFIX =      b'ray.rawdata\0'

context = zmq.Context.instance()

time.sleep(5)

socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
time.sleep(5)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:50290")
time.sleep(5)
go = True
while go:

    if socket.poll(1000):

        zframes = socket.recv_multipart(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK, copy=False)

        if (zframes[0].buffer.tobytes() == _HEARTBEAT_PREFIX):
            print ('Heartbeart')
        elif (zframes[0].buffer.tobytes() == _RAW_DATA_PREFIX):
            dataToWrite = np.frombuffer(zframes[1].buffer, dtype='i2')
            print ('Raw data: ')
            # and so on ...
```

This is the first time I am working with ZMQ and trying to port this Python code to C is a real challenge. The C code I have written now will run, but does not work properly:

```
#include "zhelpers.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{

  void *context   = zmq_ctx_new();
  void *subscriber = zmq_socket(context,ZMQ_SUB);

  int rc = zmq_connect(subscriber,"tcp://localhost:50290");
  assert(rc == 0);
  rc = zmq_setsockopt(subscriber,ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
  assert(rc == 0); 

  while (1) 
  {
    zmq_msg_t message;
    zmq_msg_init (&message);
    zmq_msg_recv (&message, subscriber,0);//, ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
    //  Process the message frame


    int size = zmq_msg_size(&message);
    char *string = malloc(size + 1);
    memcpy(string, zmq_msg_data(&message), size);


    zmq_msg_close (&message);

    string[size] = 0;
    printf("Message[%d]: %s\n", size, string);

    if (!zmq_msg_more (&message))
        break;      //  Last message frame
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code will however provide the correct size of the incoming data, but when displaying the data it shows as unreadable characters (symbols and so on..) I will need, as I do in Python, to get the incoming data as a string in order to process it further.

Comment: The C code doesn't seem to check the frame type (heartbeat/raw data). The first frame seems to be the type and if the type is raw data, then the next frame contains something that might be printable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the numpy array in Python is converted to a string array containing int's, and they where very difficult values to interpret for the C program.

By manipulating the received data I was able to extract the correct values:

```
#include "zhelpers.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{

  int i = 0;

  void *context   = zmq_ctx_new();
  void *subscriber = zmq_socket(context,ZMQ_SUB);

  int rc = zmq_connect(subscriber,"tcp://localhost:50290");
  assert(rc == 0);

  char* filter = "ray.";

  rc = zmq_setsockopt(subscriber,ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, sizeof(filter));
  assert(rc == 0); 
  int nextFrame = 0;

  while (1) 
  {

    zmq_msg_t message;
    zmq_msg_init (&message);
    zmq_msg_recv (&message, subscriber,0);//, ZMQ_NOBLOCK);

    //  Process the message frame

    int size = zmq_msg_size(&message);
    char *string = malloc(size + 1);
    memcpy(string, zmq_msg_data(&message), size);

    if (nextFrame)
    {

      zmq_msg_close (&message);
      printf("Raw data: "); 
      string[size] = 0;
      //printf("Data: %s\n", string);
      for ( i = 0; i < size; i+=2)
      {

        printf("%d ", (int16_t) ((string[i] & 0xff) +((string[i+1] & 0xff)<<8)));

      }


    }
      if (strcmp(string, "ray.rawdata") != 0)
      {
        nextFrame = 0;
        break;
      }
      else 
      {
        nextFrame = 1;

        zmq_msg_close (&message);

        string[size] = 0;
        printf("Prefix: %s\n", string);

        if (!zmq_msg_more (&message))
            break;      //  Last message frame
      }

  }}
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this only is a problem when receiving numpy arrays from Python - as long as it is a heartbeat string or whatever, there are no problems.